# Stripe Express Elements - passing email and name via the element

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

In Stripe Express Checkout element, how do I require that the user has to enter their name and email address via their wallet (Apple Pay, Google Pay, Link etc). I am trying the below but it doesn't seem to work.

Note that I want the user to specify name, email via their wallet.

```
  const options = {
    mode: 'payment',
    amount: price,
    currency: currency,
    onBehalfOf: stripeAccountId,
    emailRequired: true,
    fields: {
      name: 'auto',
      billingDetails: {
        email: 'auto',
      },
    }
  };
```

Comment: It's covered in the Stripe documentation here : https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment#handle-click-event